# Is the No-Cloning Theorem Violated in $C^\ast$-Circuit Models?

Tags: circuit-construction, mathematics, non-locality

In [Cleve, et al.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.12575), the authors discuss *self-embezzlement* of a catalyst state $\psi$, making the statement on page 2,

> [B]y local operations, state $\psi\otimes(\vert 0 \rangle \otimes \vert 0 \rangle)$
> is mapped to $\psi \otimes \psi$ within fidelity
> $1-\epsilon$.... [W]e allow the catalyst to be any pure state that is
> non-trivially entangled in the sense that it can be used to
> approximately attain the maximal violation of the CHSH inequality....

When $\epsilon=0$, this is referred to as exact self-embezzlement.  Moreover, Theorem 1.3 in the paper states, "In the $C^\ast$-circuit model, exact self-embezzlement is possible."

If $\psi$ is unknown, it seems clear that exact self-embezzlement would violate the no-cloning theorem.  However, I don't see anything in the paper that implies $\psi$ is known.  In particular the $\ast$‑automorphism, discussed at the top of page 11, does not seem to require that $\psi$ be known.

My question is,

- Does this paper imply that the no-cloning theorem is violated in $C^\ast$-circuit models?

N.B. the authors show that self-embezzlement cannot be approximated to arbitrary precision in the conventional quantum circuit model, so thinking of the results in terms of some form of closure of the conventional circuit model is not helpful.

Comment: it looks like it! btw the author is Cleve with a "C".

Comment: @Condo Thanks for catching that.  Bad typo.

Comment: also, is it clear that every state is a "catalyst" in the sense above?

Comment: Based on the quoted language, any pure state that is non-trivially entangled can be a "catalyst" state.